# Adding fragment to switch statement to allow pages to swipe across

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app, and when I open up a page I can then swipe between 'Line Details' and 'Verify Line'. However when I swipe to the second page 'Verify Line' the objects i.e. textboxes in 'Line Details' move across as well but I don't want this to happen, could anyone tell me why? I also have a fragment in my code.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new LineDetails();
    fragment.setArguments(extras);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new LineDetails();
        case 1:
            return new VerifyLine();
        default:
            return new LineDetails();

    }
}
@Override
public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    super.finishUpdate(container);
}
```

Comment: Where and how is getItem() method used?

Comment: move `Line Details TextView` in your activit's layout  and then you also have to use callback mechanism between fragments and activity to access TextView

Comment: getItem() comes from FragmentStatepagerAdapter java class, it is locked and set

Comment: I'd need some more info on how you did the swiping and what do you mean the ' the objects i.e. textboxes move across as well'